# How can I add a 1D array to a segment of a 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D NumPy array filled with zeroes (placeholder values). I would like to add a 1D array filled with ones and zeroes to a part of it. eg.

- 2D array:

  ```
  array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
  ```
- 1D array:

  ```
  array([1, 0, 1])
  ```

Desired end product: I want the array starting in position `[2, 1]`

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Or an insertion in any other position it could reasonably fit in. I have tried to do it with boolean masks but have not had any luck creating one in the correct shape. I have also tried flattening the 2D array, but couldn't figure out how to replace the values in the correct space.

Comment: Have you tried indexing the 2d array with `arr[1,2:5]`?

Comment: next time at least provide us with the correct format for the arrays (i.e. [[11,2],....] , ) , please

Comment: Can't believe I tried boolean masks but forgot about fancy indexing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed flatten the array and create a sequence of positions where you will insert your 1D array `segment`:

```
>>> pos = [1, 2]
>>> start = x.shape[1]*pos[0] + pos[1]
>>> seq = start + np.arange(len(segment))

>>> seq
array([7, 8, 9])
```

Then, you can either index the flattened array:

```
>>> x_f = x.flatten()
>>> x_f[seq] = segment
>>> x_f.reshape(x.shape)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

Alternatively, you can [`np.ravel_multi_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy.ravel_multi_index) to get `seq` and apply [`np.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) on it.

```
>>> seq = np.arange(len(segment)) + np.ravel_multi_index(pos, x.shape)
array([7, 8, 9])

>>> indices = np.unravel_index(seq, x.shape)
(array([1, 1, 1]), array([2, 3, 4]))

>>> x[indices] = segment
>>> x
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```